# gorm uniqueIndex works but doesnt store data

Tags: go, go-gorm

so I have a database which 3 tables: creditor, debtor and operation, the operation are refer to a creditor and a debtor if this debtor is already in the table I dont want that create a new row, the same for debtor, but the operation have to be storage with the id of the already in database debtor or/and creditor.

So for try to make this I put the uniqueIndex:idx_name which only storage the data if both (name/bic or name/iban) are unique, so that its good, but the problem is gorm give this error and doesnt storage the operation.

```
Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mybb`.`operations`, CONSTRAINT `fk_operations_creditor` FOREIGN KEY (`creditor_id`) REFERENCES `creditors` (`id`))
```

Is there any way to do this? or do I have to separately check if the debtor and creditor exist, save it if not or get the id if yes and later save the operation?.

Structures

```
type Creditor struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_name"`
    BIC  string `json:"bic" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_name"`
}
type Operation struct {
    gorm.Model
    Debtor     *Debtor
    Creditor   *Creditor
    Type       int    `json:"type"`
    Gateway    string `json:"gateway"`
    DebtorID   int    `json:"debtor_id"`
    CreditorID int    `json:"creditor_id"`
}
type Debtor struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_name"`
    IBAN  string `json:"iban" gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_name"`
}
```

Code

```
    var err error
    dsn := "root:changeme@tcp(localhost:3306)/mybb?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    conn, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
    }
    conn.AutoMigrate(Operation{})
    op := make([]Operation, 0)
    op = append(op, Operation{
        Debtor: &Debtor{
            IBAN: "test",
            Name: "hey"},
        Creditor: &Creditor{
            Name: "otr",
            BIC:  "hello"},
        Type:    2,
        Gateway: "sepa",
    })
    op = append(op, Operation{
        Debtor: &Debtor{
            IBAN: "test",
            Name: "hey",
        },
        Creditor: &Creditor{
            Name: "otr",
            BIC:  "hello",
        },
        Type:    2,
        Gateway: "sepa",
    })
    res := conn.Create(op)
    if res.Error != nil {
        println(res.Error.Error())
    }
```